# C# Generic Method with non-nullable generic parameter warns of possible null reference

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, nullable-reference-types

When programming today the following situation arose.
A generic method accepts a non-nullable generic parameter. The method basically just inserts the generic value into a collection. However, this gives rise to a compiler warning indicating that the generic parameter might be null. At the face of it, it seems to be a bug in the compiler and contradict the design of nullable values. However, I am sure that there is some good explanation that I am not seeing.

Consider the following simplified example of the situation:
`public void M1<T>(T t, List<object> l) => l.Add(t);`
The compiler warns that t might be null in `l.Add(t)`.

Also just for completness the following method gives the same error (as expected):
`public void M1<T>(T? t, List<object> l) => l.Add(t);`

Anyone has some good insights into this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone could call:

```
var list = new List<object>();
M1<string?>(null, list);
```

Now your list, which should only contain non-nullable objects, contains `null`. Hence the warning.

If you want to prevent `T` from being a nullable type, then:

```
public void M1<T>(T t, List<object> l) where T : notnull
{
    ...
}
```

This gives you the warning:

```
M1<string?>(null, new List<object>());
^^^^^^^^^^^
// warning CS8714: The type 'string?' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic 
// type or method 'C.M1<T>(T, List<object>)'. Nullability of type argument 'string?' doesn't
// match 'notnull' constraint.
```

If you want to let `T` be `null`, but still forbid `null` values for that `t` parameter, then:

```
public void M1<T>([DisallowNull] T t, List<object> l)
{
    ...
}
```

This gives you the warning:

```
M1<string?>(null, new List<object>());
            ^^^^
// warning CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.
```

Of course, if you want to allow `null` then your `l` needs to be a `List<object?>`.